# Acknowledgment for [FIN,PSH,ACK] combined packet

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpclient, packet-capture

How can I acknowledge a TCP packet with [FIN, PSH, ACK] flags set to 1? Do we need to acknowledge for both PSH and FIN separately or a single ACK can work in this case?

Comment: 1. ACK acknowledges sequence numbers, not flags. 2. One ACK will do for the FIN. The other flags don't occupy sequence number space and don't need acknowledging at all.

Comment: Thanks, Marquis of Lorne